# Regularization losses of custom TensorFlow layer not registering

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've created a custom layer, i.e. with lots of simplification, the relevant code is:

```
class MyConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__self, kernel_regularizer="glorot_uniform", ...):
    super(MyConv2D, self).__init__(...)
    self.kernel_regularizer=regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    ...

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(
      name="kernel",
      ...
      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer)
    self.built = True
```

The layer works as expected when using it in `tf.keras` Models. Hovewer, I'm also exposing a `tf.layers` type `my_conv2d` version, which is roughly implemented as:

```
def my_conv2d(inputs, kernel_regularizer="glorot_uniform"):
  conv2d = MyConv2D(kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)
  return conv2d.apply(inputs)
```

The problem is that that the if I now call `tf.losses.get_regularization_losses()`, I get back the empty list. If I change the implementation of `my_conv2d` to the following:

```
def my_conv2d(inputs, kernel_regularizer="glorot_uniform"):
  conv2d = MyConv2D(kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)
  print(conv2d.losses)
  return conv2d.apply(inputs)
```

I see that it correctly prints the regularization loss. However, this only works in single-GPU training. Using `MirroredStrategy` I get an exception inside `_tensor_conversion_mirrored` on the line `assert not as_ref`. I assume this is because I'm trying to print the tensor within some context handler that creates the two towers.

What am I doing wrong? How should I access the regularization loss as a user of `my_conv2d` layer and how should I register the losses in the `my_conv2d` layer? Compared to the implementation of `tf.layers.conv2d`, I don't see that I'm missing any code.